# React useRef not working with Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, input, textfield

why is useRef not working with Material UI TextField but works fine with a traditional html input element?

**The UI:**

I have a Textfield input element and above it I have a list of buttons (letters from the latin alphabet, special characters). I can focus the input bar when the component renders the first time, but if I click on one of the buttons above the input, the focus is not back on the input bar.

**What I tried so far**

```
const Search = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
 

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleLatinButton = (letter) => {
   inputRef.current.focus();
    setSearchTerm(searchTerm + letter);
  };


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    History.push("/?q=" + searchTerm);
    props.onFormSubmit(searchTerm, optionValue);
    setSearchTerm("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const q = params.get("q");
    setSearchTerm(q);
    inputRef.current.focus();
    
  }, []); // Am I missing something here in the array?
```

**JSX**

```
    <Button letter="č" handleLatinButton={handleLatinButton} />
    <Button letter="ḍ" handleLatinButton={handleLatinButton} />
     ... 
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="Search..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
        ref={inputRef}
        autoFocus="true"
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <IconButton type="submit">
                <SearchIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </form>
```

If I replace TextField with input, the focus works after I click on one of the latin buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way MUI handles the ref...

```
<TextField
    fullWidth
    label="Search..."
    value={searchTerm}
    onChange={handleChange}
  change this >>>  ref={inputRef}
  for this >>> inputRef={inputRef}
    autoFocus="true"
    InputProps={{
      endAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <IconButton type="submit">
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      ),
    }}
  />
```

perhaps to avoid confusion change the ref name